# jquery field validation is not working with chrome's autofill

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

Using html5, I tried add autocomplete="off" to the form and to the inputs and nothing helps. The autofill from chrome is still there and it won't let the form submit.

I have basic jquery field validation script to check for length and set required fields.

the form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="loginForm" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="text" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login">
</form>
```

please help me fix this!

Comment: try `autocomplete="off"` or `value=""` on input fields

Comment: my value has php tag inside of it for the username to echo back in case the form didn't go through

Answer (score 0):

`autocomplete="off"` will not have any effect on browser's autofill.

It makes the browser not show suggestions based on user history. That's it.

However try adding `value=""` to the input and see if it works for you.

Comment: but i need the value to have a php echo inside of it in case the wrong username was entered, it shows the username there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar problem, I 'solved' it this way. It's more of an ugly horrible hack than a fix, but it did the trick for me,Wouldn't work without the setTimeout either in my case, YMMV. I placed the code AFTER the initialisation of the jQuery UI autocompleter I'm using.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') >= 0) {
         setTimeout(function () {            
          document.getElementById('myInputId').autocomplete = 'off';}, 1); 
};}
```